# How to display a multi-valued heatmap chart

Tags: info-visualisation, data, graphs

I will try to describe the issue in a simulation similar to my case, I went with the vehicles:

A company that performs tests for vehicles of the types *(Truck, Car, Motorcycle)* wants to display score statistics for each category of test for each type of vehicle.

**Types of vehicles:** Truck, Car, Motorcycle

**Types of test categories:** Safety, Engine, Brakes, Switch, Wheels.

To display the data with combinations of vehicle type to test category I created a heatmap:

[image]

Each block is a combination of vehicle to a test category for the vehicle and a score value between 0.0 to 1.0, score of success, and the color goes from red, yellow, green based on the score.

Now this is great for my case, but what happens if a vehicle can have multiple versions? let's say up to 4 versions per vehicle type, so truck can be Truck A, or Truck B, .. C .. D.

How can I visualize that data for each truck type inside a combination of vehicle to test category without creating a mess?

Here's what I tried:

[image]

In this heatmap, each block represents a combination of vehicle type to a test category, and inside of each block it contains 4 sub-blocks, where each sub block is a version of vehicle.

Hovering that will display a tooltip with information with a score value of each version, and each sub block will get a color based on it's version score.

With a few test categories and vehicle types it looks okay, but if I will have like 10 vehicles and 10 categories, things are getting messy.

Is there a better way to display this sort of information?

Answer (score 3):

**There will be a lot of squares** – this is something that we cannot avoid and we need to acknowledge that. i.e 10 categories x 10 vehicles x 10 vehicle types. Which means there will be 1000 colored squares in total!

From my limited understanding of the use case, I'm making the assumption that:

- **(But) It wouldn't make sense for the user to see all 1000 squares in one go.**

So I can suggest 3 ideas for it:

**Suggestion part 1:**

- Show the **AGGREGATE VALUE** of truck A, B, C & D first (if it makes sense for your product. Else this is just a dumb idea. lol). On click – zoom in and show the specific values of Truck A, B, C & D.
  [image]

**Suggestion part 2:**

- Scrolling vertically is easier and more familier than having a horizontal scroll. So we move the entity that has most chance for 'highest count' to vertical axis.
  [image]

**Suggestion part 3:**

- Highlight the red and orange squares to the user on top. **So they get the information that they need to focus on, first!**
  [image]

P.S: These are ideas built on top of your direction. There should be better & novel ideas that others could suggest – looking forward to seeing them too!

Comment: Hey thank you for the suggestions! I think that suggestion #2 is the only relevant one for my case because the whole idea of this heatmap is to give the user an easy way to see an overview to compare between versions for each test, not just on hovering tooltip. The only issue I have with #2 is that there are too many labels and version names can be longer.

Comment: No problem mate! I am more curious to solve this now hehe.   For that, could you answer me one qn: "why does your user want to see the overview of each test in one glance?"

Comment: Hey Kishan, thank you. You need to see overview of each test because it's not really about vehicles, basically it's a tool that is used to test generative AI models like GPT, and you want to test many test categories, I can't really explain what is the X/Y in my case because it's a bit complicated, needs lot more context. But this gives you a better view to compare between models, in our case its the version of the vehicles for each type. This lets you view which model failed where, and you can compare it to multiple categories

Comment: @benberizovsky – I don't really get what you mean. Maybe you can help explain this a bit more – "it's not really about vehicles, basically it's a tool that is used to test generative AI models like GPT, and you want to test many test categories"

Comment: I would love to explain it, but I need to share more context which is less suitable here because its too long. If you are interested leave me a way to contact you. I accepted your bounty